# SSH multihop configuration

Tags: ssh

I've been trying to setup some sort of configuration on my laptop , so I'd be able to connect to a server using SSH , directly , which i have indirect access to , 
i've found a great configuration here :
https://superuser.com/a/303487/133737
so sofar i've made this configuration :

```
Host terzo , gw02, ipsec

ProxyCommand ssh zenoss nc -w 10 %h %p
```

but i want to be able to ssh to forinstance `zenipsec` , and it'd directly go through `zenoss`

I'm hoping to create something like this :

```
Host zen*

ProxyCommand ssh zenoss nc -w 10 %h `echo %h | cut -f2-100 -dn`
```

i guess the last part `` `echo %h | cut -f2-100 -dn` `` , doesn't work .
can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2):

A useful configuration which I use is this:

```
Host *%*
    ProxyCommand ssh $(echo %h | cut -d%% -f2-) nc $(echo %h | cut -d%% -f1) %p
```

It allows you to setup arbitrary hops by separating the hosts with the `%` sign. For example, `ssh zenipsec%zenoss` would hop through zenoss to get to zenipsec.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling netcat to use `zenipsec` as host and `ipsec` as port. The following should be correct:

```
nc -w 10 `echo %h | cut -f2-100 -dn` %p
```

---

A much cleaner way to do this is to write a script that acts as a ProxyCommand; for example, `~/bin/proxycommand-zen`

```
#!/bin/sh
host=$1
port=$2
exec ssh zenoss nc -w 10 ${host#zen} $port
```