# Remote editing with Eclipse IDE through an SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, eclipse, sftp, tunnel

I work on a server that is behind a firewall and only accessible from the outside through an intermediary. When I work from home, I need to log into serverA and from there ssh to server B, the server my work is on.

I figured out how to set up Eclipse to edit remote files through sftp. This works onsite where I can connect directly to serverB.

But I can't figure out a way to sftp to serverB through serverA when I'm working from home.

Suggestions?

Is there some way I can create a sort of virtual server for serverB so it looks like I'm not doing a hop? Perhaps using a tunnel of some sort?

**EDIT:** Here is some information about Eclipse settings that might be useful. The dialog for establishing a new connection looks like this:

[image]

If I click on "Configure proxy settings" I get this dialog.

[image]

If there was some way to put an explicit ssh command in Eclipse, I would just tunnel. Is there a way to do this through the proxy settings?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://superuser.com/questions/303486/sftp-over-double-server-hop

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I had not seen that. Seems party applicable. I did not know you could include a proxy command in an ssh. However, as you can see, you don't put in an explicit ssh command. If I click on "Add host" I just get a text box to enter host names separated by commas. Suggestions?

Comment: Would it be possible to map serverB as a remote drive in Windows?

Comment: I am sorry, i do not know Windows well enough. You can do it in Linux with `sshfs`; so, given, my ignorance, you may try googling `Windows equivalent of sshfs` and see what comes up.

Comment: Very good suggestion. Thanks. I am finding solutions for that. I haven't found any descriptions of how to tunnel yet (make the hop), but there is probably a way out there somewhere.