# Tunneling sftp 3 Hopd

Tags: linux, ssh, cmd.exe, sftp, ssh-tunnel

Hi I'm newby to using ssh and sftp The scenario is the following one: I have to transfer a big file from local to a server passing through proxy server. local <----> proxy <-----> destination

The problem is that the file don't fit on proxy server, so i cannot perform sftp in two steps. I have to define a tunneling between local and destination, through proxy, but I don't know how. The base command is this:

```
ssh user@hop1.com ssh user2@destination.com
```

but this command doesn't work because I have to specify the ports. How can I set up a tunnel in that scenario to use sftp?

Thanks in advance Marco

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFTP over double server hop](http://superuser.com/questions/303486/sftp-over-double-server-hop)

Comment: No this approach give me back: "Write failed: broken pipe"

Comment: No it doesn't work, each time that I run the comand line the answer is connection timed out.

Comment: Then post the verbose log to see what is going on there.

Comment: @Jakuje channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
               stdio forwarding failed
               ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
               Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer.

Comment: That does not look like whole verbose log. Add `-vvv` to both `ssh` and `sftp` and edit the question with the result.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Don't use `netcat`. Use the `-W` switch instead:

```
sftp -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p myfirsthop" mydestination
```

You can make this default by editing the `ssh_config` file, by default `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host mydestination
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p myfirsthop
```

Comment: the following message appear, don't log in the proxy too: >>>channel 0:open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
               stdio forwarding failed
               ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote      host
               Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer.